# How to create multiple products (item lines) in zoho books API when creating an invoice

Tags: php, laravel, api, zoho, zohobooks

I'm trying to create a Zoho books invoice through their API and I'm trying to include multiple item lines, how do I do that?

I tried

```php
'line_items' => [
    [
        'item_id'           => '7131',
        'description'       => something
        'rate'              => somthing
        'quantity'          => something
    ]
]
```

duplicating this with the same tag and it goes through but only one product line was created then I tried changing it to line_items2 and I get this error

> resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"code":15,"message":"Please ensure that the line_items2 has less than 100 characters."}

Comment: It's difficult to provide recommendations without seeing a more complete code example of what is not working. [More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

For creating an Invoice with multiple line items in Zoho Books via API call, the line_items has to be in the below format:

```
"line_items": [
{
"item_id": "10114090XXXX29039",
"rate": 50000,
"description": "DESC",
"quantity": "1.00"
},
{
"item_id": "1011409XXXX43097",
"rate": 2550,
"description": "DESC",
"quantity": "1.00"
}
]
```

Once done, the Invoice with the multiple lines should be created in Zoho Books

Comment: can you give me an example of invoice insert zoho crm api ? I am not able to find it in documentation.